# Java Date (Calendar) calculating the start of a day in local time given a date time

Tags: java, date, calendar

All,

Having a hard day in the office with this one...  I am trying to workout the start of a day in Local Time, i.e. Midnight 00:00:00, given any calendar date.

Given the following days, I want to calculate the start of the day at local time midnight:

```
       Time                     Start Day (Local)            Start Day (GMT)
2011-03-27 00:00:00 GMT -->     2011-03-27 00:00:00 GMT -->  2011-03-27 00:00:00 GMT
2011-03-27 01:00:00 GMT -->     2011-03-27 00:00:00 GMT -->  2011-03-27 00:00:00 GMT
2011-03-27 02:00:00 GMT -->     2011-03-27 00:00:00 GMT -->  2011-03-27 00:00:00 GMT
2011-04-01 00:00:00 BST -->     2011-04-01 00:00:00 BST -->  2011-03-31 23:00:00 GMT
2011-10-30 00:00:00 BST -->     2011-10-30 00:00:00 BST -->  2011-10-29 23:00:00 GMT
2011-10-30 01:00:00 BST -->     2011-10-30 00:00:00 BST -->  2011-10-29 23:00:00 GMT
2011-10-30 01:00:00 GMT -->     2011-10-30 00:00:00 BST -->  2011-10-29 23:00:00 GMT
2011-11-01 00:00:00 GMT -->     2011-11-01 00:00:00 GMT -->  2011-11-01 00:00:00 GMT
```

At present, I am parsing the String Time into a GregorianCalendar using a SimpleDateFormat.  This gives me the GMT/UTC time to calculate from.

So I have some code which parses the string into a GregorianCalendar:

```
public GregorianCalendar getCalendar(String dateTime) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(dateTime, new ParsePosition(0)));

    return cal;
}
```

Now I need to set it to midnight locally:

```
public void setToStartOfDayLocally(GregorianCalendar cal) {
    ????
}
```

I am not too sure what I need to do at the minute with the Calendar.  Unfortunately we are not moving to JODA date in the near future.  I am also not accounting for different time zones with my example.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Andez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code might solve your issue. I am using it to convert from time in local timezone to another.

```
public static Date convertLocalDateToDateTimezone( Date localDate, String timezone ) {
   TimeZone localTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
   TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone( timezone );
   long gmtMillis = localDate.getTime();
   long result = gmtMillis + timezone.getOffset( gmtMillis ) - localTimeZone.getOffset(     gmtMillis );
   return new Date( result );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to set all of the time parts to zero. You can use:

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

(Assuming you've got the time zone in the calendar set properly.)

Note that that isn't *necessarily* valid though - in some time zones (e.g. Brazil), at a daylight saving transition midnight either occurs twice or not at all.

Personally I'd start making noises about moving to Joda Time though, which makes all of this a lot simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

You are using outmoded classes. In Java 8 and later, use built-in [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework.

Do not assume the day starts at the time `00:00:00.0`. Because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) the start-of-day may vary by time zone. Let the java.time classes determine the correct time with a call to [`LocalDate::atStartOfDay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-).

Avoid using 3-4 letter zone abbreviations such as `BST`, `EST`, and so on. They are neither standardized nor unique. Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Apply a time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Extract a date-only value from that date-time, a [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). Apply a time zone with a call to [`atStartOfDay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-) to get back to a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) set to the first moment of the day in that time zone.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = localDate.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

Tip: Avoid the word “midnight”. Does not have a precise definition. Some people think of trying to determine the last moment of the day which is a problem because of an infinitely divisible fraction of a second. Some people think of the the special string “24:00” to indicate the stroke of midnight which further confuses date-time handling. Experience from the Joda-Time project teaches us that it is best to focus on “first moment of the day” as a clear and precise meaning. Also, be aware that the first moment is *not* always `00:00:00`, due to Daylight Saving Time (DST) and other anomalies in some time zones. That is why we depend on the `atStartOfDay` method rather than hard-code a zero-time-of-day.