# replace timezone of a date by other timezone, date should be same

Tags: java, date

I have one date let say

```
Date date = new Date(); //Thu Mar 31 04:34:37 AKDT 2016
```

I want to convert it to another date:

```
Thu Mar 31 00:00:00 UTC 2016
```

Means I did two changes:

1. reset time to 00
2. rest timezone to UTC, but date should be same i.e 31 .

I wrote this code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
        calendar.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
        return calendar.getTime();
```

but it is giving `Wed Mar 30 10:30:00 AKDT 2016` but I want `Wed Mar 31 00:00:00 UTC 2016`.

**How would I achieve this?**

Comment: `dateString.replaceAll("(\\d{2}:){2}\\d{2} [A-Z]+", "00:00:00 UTC")`?

Comment: not it's not String obj. It's simply a date. i.e new Date();

Comment: @AbhishekRajawat How do you obtain the original date? Just `new Date()`?

Comment: yes, just new Date();

Comment: @AbhishekRajawat Can you use Java 8 features?

Comment: No, I am using java 7 in my project

Comment: why would you not just use java 8?

Comment: Duplicate for the second part of Question: [Java Date (Calendar) calculating the start of a day in local time given a date time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7585745/642706)

Answer (score 4):

You should specify timezone and proper format in your formatter, and output according to that format:

```
Date date = new Date();
TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(utc);
calendar.setTime(date);

// ... erase time as you do now

// here is a format you need (taken from `Date.toString()`)
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
df.setTimeZone(utc);
System.out.println(df.format(calendar.getTime()));  // Thu Mar 31 00:00:00 UTC 2016
```

When you try to print a `Date` as `date.toString()`, you will always get result in your default timezone, because `Date` itself is just a moment in time and it doesn't keep any information about timezone.

If you just need to adjust current datetime to midnight in UTC, your code is correct. `10:30:00 AKDT` should not confuse you -- it means only that when it is midnight in UTC, in your timezone it is 10:30.

Comment: Above code is correct, but this thing is in String format and I want it in date, when I convert it into date, it's format changes.

Comment: can u please help me, how can I remove timezone from my date?. and result should be in Date format not String.

Comment: @AbhishekRajawat `Date` itself *does not* keep timezone. You see timezone only when you perform `date.toString()`--so timezone is a part of *representation of date*, not *date* itself. So question about replacing/removing timezone from `Date` is senseless.

Comment: the problem is, I have to save this date in database, and column in DB has Date type. so I can't save it in String.

Comment: @AbhishekRajawat no problem, save it as a `Date`, not string. When you create a canendar which timezone is UTC, then erase time values, resulting `Date` is a midnight in UTC (but may be not midnight in another time zones)

Comment: @AbhishekRajawat when there is a midnight in UTC, in your timezone it is 10:30, that's why `date.toString()` prints 10:30.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a problem with printing/string conversion.

Internally `Calendar` and `Date` will store the the date-time as milliseconds since the epoch (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 **GMT**). 
When converting the `Date` to a string the output will always be **converted** to your timezone.

Your date `Thu Mar 31 04:34:37 AKDT 2016` is stored as (`1459427677000`) and would print `Thu Mar 31 14:34:37 CEST 2016` for a JVM running in `CEST` timezone.

Your code looks correct to to me, the returned `Date`'s `getTime()` should be `1459382400000`. In your case, you can do a quick check using `date.getGMTString()` which should print `Mar 31 00:00:00 UTC 2016`.